# python: return list from generator function

Tags: python

I have simple function that I am trying to convert into generator that return batch output. Here is code

```
# Simple function, working but too slow once get big list

def compute_add():
    data = range(5)

    cases = list(itertools.permutations(data, 2))

    print(f"{cases=}")

    result = []

    for x, y in cases:
        ans = x + y
        result.append(ans)

    return result

report = compute_add()
print(f"{report=}")
```

So in first attempt I tried it to convert into generator that returns single output

```
# Generator single value and working
def compute_add_generator():
    data = range(5)

    cases = list(itertools.permutations(data, 2))

    print(f"{cases=}")

    for x, y in cases:
        ans = x + y
        yield ans


report = []
for res in compute_add_generator():
    report.append(res)

print(f"{report=}")
```

In the second attempt I tried it to convert to a generator that returns batch output(list)

```
# Generator batch output and not working
def compute_add_generator_batch(batch_size):
    data = range(5)

    cases = list(itertools.permutations(data, 2))

    print(f"{cases=}")

    res = []
    for x, y in cases:
        ans = x + y
        
        if len(res) != batch_size:
            res.append(ans)
            continue

        yield res

        res = []


batch_size=3  # it can vary
for res in compute_add_generator_batch(batch_size):
    print(f"{res=}")
```

It is giving me wrong output as it always skiping the 4th output

```
cases=[(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4), (1, 0), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 0), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 4), (4, 0), (4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 3)]
res=[1, 2, 3]
res=[1, 3, 4]
res=[2, 3, 5]
res=[3, 4, 5]
res=[4, 5, 6]
```

Expected output

```
res=[1, 2, 3]
res=[4, 1, 3]
res=[4, 5, 2]
res=[3, 5, 6]
res=[3, 4, 5]
res=[7, 4, 5]
res=[6, 7]
```

I tried storing 4th result in `res = [ans]` still wrong output as misses last row.

What I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an version that supports the `batch_size` parameter:

```py
import itertools


def compute_add_generator(batch_size):
    assert batch_size > 0

    data = range(5)

    batch = []
    for x, y in itertools.permutations(data, 2):
        ans = x + y
        batch.append(ans)
        if len(batch) == batch_size:
            yield batch
            batch = []

    # the rest:
    if batch:
        yield batch


report = []
for res in compute_add_generator(3):
    report.append(res)

print(f"{report=}")
```

Prints:

```
report = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 1, 3], [4, 5, 2], [3, 5, 6], [3, 4, 5], [7, 4, 5], [6, 7]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Minimal fix to your existing logic:

```
if len(res) != batch_size:
    res.append(ans)
    continue
```

Change that to:

```
res.append(ans)
if len(res) != batch_size:
    continue
```

A more Pythonic refactor is:

```
def compute_add_generator_batch(batch_size):
    data = range(5)
    perms = itertools.permutations(data, 2)
    batches = itertools.batched(perms, batch_size)
    for batch in batches:
        yield [x + y for x, y in batch]
```

*Note*: the utility [`itertools.batched`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.batched) is new in Python 3.12. For older Python versions, it is roughly equivalent to:

```
def batched(iterable, n):
    # batched('ABCDEFG', 3) --> ABC DEF G
    if n < 1:
        raise ValueError('n must be at least one')
    it = iter(iterable)
    while batch := tuple(itertools.islice(it, n)):
        yield batch
```

Comment: Hi wim, Thanks. I was not aware of this new feature `batched` looking good but unfortunately I am on 3.11